# Any ideas of what could cause System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled property to throw a System.NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

Here is the stack trace:

> 2012-03-16 19:15:09Z E System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at System.Timers.Timer.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
>      at System.Timers.Timer.Stop()

Here's the code:

Timer declared as private member variable.

```
Private _myTimer As System.Timers.Timer
```

Initialize timer method.

```
Private Sub InitializeMyTimer()

    _myTimer = New System.Timers.Timer

    _myTimer.Interval = My.Settings.TimeoutSeconds * 1000
    _myTimer.Start()

    AddHandler _myTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf MyTimer_Elapsed

End Sub
```

Timer elapsed method.  WsMethodAsync calls an .asmx web service method.

```
Private Sub MyTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)

    Try

        _myTimer.Stop()

        Using thisWSHelper As New WSHelper

            thisWsHelp.WsMethodAsync()

        End Using

        _myTimer.Start()

    Catch ex As Exception

      LogAndShowException(ex)

    End Try

End Sub
```

The timer has to have a value or else the Timer.Stop() call would be throwing the exception.  This is a sporadic error and I'm just trying to see if anyone has experienced this before or if anyone has any ideas of what could be causing it.  It is occuring in a WinForms application in the event handler for the Elapsed event of the Timer, but it is only occuring sporadically on the users computer.  I haven't been able to reproduce the error myself.

Comment: Broken multi-threading, i.e. it's likely you access the timer from multiple threads.

Comment: You should edit the question and add some code.  (I've voted to reopen)

Comment: Almost all .net objects can only be written to from a single thread at a time.

Comment: The important code still isn't there. I suspect you're modifying the timer from a callback on the wrong thread. What does `WsMethodAsync` do?

Comment: Wow, downvotes...closed question...StackOverflow sure is picky these days.

Comment: WsMethodAsync calls an .asmx web service method.

Comment: why are you using a `Systems.Timers.Timer` instead of a winforms timer?

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's assume you realized that the System.Timers.Timer class implements IDisposable and that you wrote code to properly dispose the timer like you should:

```
Private Sub OnDisposed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Disposed
    If myTimer IsNot Nothing Then
        myTimer.Dispose()
        myTimer = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Yes, that's going to go kaboom once in a while.  The Elapsed event is raised by a thread pool thread and can start running at any odd time.  It can take several seconds if the threadpool is particularly busy.  Disposing the timer does *not* prevent the event from running, the tp thread is already in flight.  So with this particular code, it is highly likely that you'll get a NRE.  Just sometimes, never when you debug the code.

Stopping a System.Timers.Timer in a controlled way is quite difficult, you can never be sure that the Elapsed event won't fire after you disabled it.  Write defensively and keep in mind that it is possible.  And favor System.Threading.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason you're seeing these random exceptions:

A `System.Timers.Timer` uses as [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), and, as Hans Passant said, each iteration is done on another thread. This makes it possible for your `Elapsed` event to be raised after you disable the timer because a new iteration can be started before the previous one is done.

The way the `System.Timers.Timer` works, disabling it disposes the underlying `System.Threading.Timer` and sets it to Nothing. In a rare (is this word redundant?) race condition, your timer will attempt to run `Dispose` on its underlying timer while it is set to Nothing, resulting in that `NullReferenceException`.

---

One solution would be to set the `Timer.AutoReset` property to False and restart the timer in your `Elapsed` event.